# How would I configure an OpenVPN servers outbound connections through an HTTP/S proxy?

Tags: linux, tcp, proxy, openvpn, tunnel

I really would like to create an OpenVPN server that can passthrough all incoming connections out through an HTTP/S proxy.

For example like this.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2atBH.png)

Reasoning is that I would like to bypass detections on a service that checks for proxy connections on the guest through checking if system proxies are enabled on their device.

I think I had read somewhere it is possible with the correct IPtables configuration.

I would appreciate the help a bunch!

Comment: Forwarding a connection through a proxy would require rewriting the application layer of the connection. This is not possible with iptables alone. Moreover a HTTP proxy usually expects to do the DNS resolving itself which would require a hostname given in the proxy request. This is not available at the network layer. It could be extracted from the application (HTTP request, TLS SNI) though. Doable, but I don't know of any existing software for this very specific use case. Apart from that the question is unrelated to programming, i.e. off-topic here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.